# Is it possible to implement a view using native code in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-ndk

I'm trying to make an app which has a view that uses a lot of native modules, and it would be better if I organized my code so that the code for that view is all native. I know you can build native activities but I don't need to do that. Just implementing this one view in native code (so that its code lives inside a shared library) will be enough. Are there any resources/code examples that demonstrate what I want?

Answer (score 0):

To create a view, all you need to do is derive a class from View, and implement the 2 main constructors-  MyView(Context), MyView(Context, AttributeSet), and MyView(Context, AttributeSet, int).  If you want to control how it draws, override onDraw(Canvas).  Beyond that it depends on what you want to do in it.